# Rake task for MSBuild finds different version than my VS

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, rake

I'm having some trouble getting a rake build script to work locally (it runs fine on our CI server), because it for some reason uses an incorrect version of `msbuild`. I can also build it fine from inside Visual Studio 2013.

The following existed in my web project's `.csproj` file when I started working on this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<!--<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />-->
<!-- Above commented out because it fails - keep reading for why... -->
```

I added the following target for debugging purposes:

```
<Target Name="ShowVersions">
    <Message Text="VS version: $(VisualStudioVersion)" />
    <Message Text="VSToolsPath: $(VSToolsPath)" />
</Target>
```

and the accompanying `rake` task:

```
msbuild :debug_versions do |msb|
  msb.solution = "src/NCVIB.WebMVC/NCVIB.WebMVC.csproj"
  msb.targets :ShowVersions
end
```

Now, if I run the `ShowVersions` target from my terminal directly using `MSBuild MyWebProject.csproj /t:ShowVersions` it correctly identifies my VS version as 12.0. If I run `rake debug_versions`, it says the VS version is 11.0, and consequentially the import of `WebApplications.targets` fails (the path doesn't exist).

How do I make the `rake` task pick up the same VS version as plain `msbuild` does?